# Bootstrap 4 card-footer fill remaining height of column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project that uses [bootstrap cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#header-and-footer). I have 3 cards, one for each column, that need to be equal heights. They look like this:

[image: 3 cards that need equal heights]

The **B** and **C** cards need to fill the remaining height of their parent columns. I know that I can do this by adding the h-100 class to the cards, but then it will look like this:

[image]

I don't want the height of the card-body to fill the rest of the column. I want the height of the card-footer to fill the rest of the column. Like this:

[image]

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body lead text-center">
          <strong>A</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam euismod nisl sed commodo
            commodo. Donec nec lectus nec tortor feugiat accumsan id sit amet mauris. Nunc interdum
            ut arcu nec lobortis.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body lead text-center">
          <strong>B</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body lead text-center">
          <strong>C</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the footer height and card height to `h-100` does the trick. Run the snippet below and view in full page.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body lead text-center">
          <strong>A</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted h-100">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam euismod nisl sed commodo commodo. Donec nec lectus nec tortor feugiat accumsan id sit amet mauris. Nunc interdum ut arcu nec lobortis.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body lead text-center">
          <strong>B</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted h-100">
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body lead text-center">
          <strong>C</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted h-100">
          Lorem ipsum
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought I tried that, but I guess I removed the h-100 class from the card and tried it on the footer. I'm not sure why I didn't leave both. Thank you!